# How to manipulate multiple variables (79x1532) with R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I am a newbie struggling to learn data wrangling. Currently I am stuck in data wrangling of 79x1532 data frame.

My data frame has 79 sample rows and 1,532 columns-2 sample identifier columns, 1,530 chemical concentration columns(79x1,532) as shown below.

```
wc_sample_conc_df
# A tibble: 79 x 1,532
   `Sample Name` `Sample Number` `1,2,4-Trichlor… `1,2-Dibromo-3-… `o-Dichlorobenz… `1,3-Dichlorobe… `p-Dichlorobenz… `1,4-Naphthoqui…
   <chr>         <chr>           <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
 1 CAS 001       A191916         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
 2 CAS 002       A191917         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
 3 CAS 003       A191918         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
 4 CAS 004       A191919         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
 5 CAS 005       A191920         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
 6 CAS 006       A191921         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
 7 CAS 007       A191922         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
 8 CAS 08        A191923         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
 9 CAS 009       A191924         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
10 CAS 010       A191925         <276             <423             <340             <340             <340             <6.32e+006      
# … with 69 more rows, and 1,524 more variables:
```

My goal is to

1 identify variables containing "<";

2 remove "<" and convert variable type to numeric from character;

3 divide values where "<" originally existed by 2

For example, I want to manipulate values "<276" in [1:10,3] to 138  at the end of task.

4 After step 1-3, my ultimate goal is to add flag column having 0 or 1 for each variable.

For example, 138 in [1:10,3] and smaller variables in the same column [,3] will be marked as flag == 0. Other variables greater than 138 in the same column [,3] will be marked as flag == 1. I will use this values in flag to calculate prevalence of chemicals in samples(n=79).

However, I am still stuck in step 1-3.

For task 1-3, I used the following command for one chemical, **`1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Concentration`** (`wc_sample_conc_df[1,3]`)

```
wc_sample_conc_df %>%
  mutate(`1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Concentration` = case_when(
    grepl("<", `1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Concentration`) ~ `1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Concentration`)) %>% str_remove("<") %>% as.numeric() %>% . / 2
    TRUE ~ numeric(`1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Concentration`)
```

And I got this error message and have no idea how to fix or where to startover..

```
Error in .(.) : could not find function "."
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
2: In wc_sample_conc_df %>% mutate(`1,2,4-Trichlorobenzene Concentration` = case_when(grepl("<",  : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I also wonder if there is better way to do this procedure with entire variables in the data frame(79x1,532). I am trying to find some examples, but only able to find simple examples of  smaller data frame. Thank you for your help in advance!

=====

@akrun Thank you for your answer. I tried with command suggested in your answer and got another error. Could you please help me which parenthesis I should add or remove?

```
> wc_sample_conc_df %>%
+ mutate(across(where(~ any(str_detect(., fixed("<"))), 
+                    ~ {tmp <- as.numeric(str_remove(., fixed("<")))
+                    case_when(str_detect(., fixed("<"))~ tmp/2, TRUE ~ tmp)))

Error: unexpected ')' in:
"                   ~ {tmp <- as.numeric(str_remove(., fixed("<")))
                   case_when(str_detect(., fixed("<"))~ tmp/2, TRUE ~ tmp))"
```

Comment: @akrun has answered your question as asked.  I'd add that you will also probably find your life is much easier if you make your dataset [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Here, that would mean using `pivot_longer` to create a data frame with columns (say) SampleName, SampleNumber, Analyte and Concentration, with 79x1532 rows.  (It might also be worthfile creating sopmething like LLQ to flag those values that originally had "<".  Why?  Apart from anythinge else, tidyverse verbs are designed to work with tidy data.

Comment: @Limey Thank you for comment. original raw data was generated from GC/MS of 1530 chemicals and "<" means analyzed chemical showed below detection limit in sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop `across` the columns `where` there are `any` substring having `<`, then use `case_when` to divide those elements having the `<` in each column, after converting to numeric or else return the numeric element

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
wc_sample_conc_df %>%
   mutate(across(where(~ any(str_detect(., fixed("<")))), 
         ~ {tmp <- as.numeric(str_remove(., fixed("<")))
            case_when(str_detect(., fixed("<"))~ tmp/2, TRUE ~ tmp)}))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with your command, but got another error.
```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"                   ~ {tmp <- as.numeric(str_remove(., fixed("<")))
                   case_when(str_detect(., fixed("<"))~ tmp/2, TRUE ~ tmp))"
```

Comment: @JYL Sorry, that was a missing `)` at the line with `where`.  Can you try again